# best method to call repetitive code with sql code

Tags: shell-script

I must develop some shell scripts that call some repetitive code that execute sql commands to database.
What is the best method to make these, with functions in an external shell script, with external shell script with these sql commands or why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write it as a function and include it in your script.

For example, write a "util" or "function script". lets call it `util.sh` and it has just functions in it:

```
#!/bin/sh

sqlCall () {
   echo "sqlCall(), \$1:["${1}"]"
}

repeatedFunction () {
   echo "repeated x:["${1}"] times"
   RETURNVAR=`date`
}
```

And then `script1.sh` and `script2.sh` can include `util.sh` like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# script 1 - includes util.sh, calls only sqlCall

# Include the functions
. /path/to/util.sh

var="s1 s2 s3"
for s in $var
do
    sqlCall $s
done
```

And this is `script2.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# script 2 - includes util.sh, calls only repeatedFunction

# Include the functions
. /path/to/util.sh

i=0
while [ $i -lt 4 ]
do
    repeatedFunction $i
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
echo "Date: ${RETURNVAR}"
```

And the result for this would be:

```
sh ./script1.sh

sqlCall(), $1:[s1]
sqlCall(), $1:[s2]
sqlCall(), $1:[s3]

sh ./script2.sh
repeated x:[0] times
repeated x:[1] times
repeated x:[2] times
repeated x:[3] times
Date: Fri Jun 16 21:15:24 AEST 2017
```

Comment: Thanks. My English is poor and I didn't explain well. I mean that these functions are called repeatedly from different shell scripts. So in one shell-script I call function A 2 times, in shell script B 3 times, in shell script C 2 times ....

Comment: @user650034 Made an update to show you how to break up the script to multiple files and include the parts.

Comment: Thanks! No problem if these functions return values?

Comment: @user650034 See second update. Added `RETURNVAR` to the `repeatedFunction` function. Shell script functions only return `0` or greater. You can set value to variable within a function and then read the variable after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL commands do not depend on the results of previous SQL commands, just pipe them to the SQL client, or store them in a text file and feed that to the SQL client:

```
while [ some condition ]; do
    # something that sets val1, val2 and val3 in this example
    # output INSERT statement (for example):
    printf 'INSERT INTO t (c1, c2, c3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);\n' "$val1" "$val2" "$val3"
done | mysql -h server database
```

The thing you should *avoid* is to loop over the call to an SQL client, such as

```
while ...; do
    echo "statement" | mysql -h server database
done
```

This would perform the connection and authentication for each statement, and will be *exceptionally* slow.